# IIS closing connection and throwing 500 randomly when using HTTP connection: keep-alive

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, iis, asp.net-web-api

We have a 10 batch jobs that call internal API that lives on IIS. When doing load testing and calling the WEB API post method from all 10 batch jobs, we will randomly get 500 responses from the server. If we supply 10000 messages after couple hundred of the messages being processed, we will notice 10 messages in a row that fail with 500. Then it just starts working again and we will not notice another error for a while.

After some research we realized what is happening is the IIS is closing the connection between the client and the server and the response of the request is 500 (Internal Server Error). Connection: Keep-Alive request header is being supplied with every message. We are getting into problems of not knowing if the 500 is occurring because the API failed with unexpected error or the server closed the connection.

My question is, is there a way to figure out if the 500 was caused by the connection being closed by the server?

Should IIS be throwing a 500 or can IIS be configured to send some other type of response when connection is being closed? Since there is really no problems with the message it self we would like to reprocess the message if this connection issue occurs and not respond back to the client with 500 thinking it's the message that caused the API to fail.

Comment: 500 or 500 Internal Server Error in my opinion is the worst error ever, it's just a general error that means, "There's a problem with your server, we don't know what it is, but it's wrong."  Sometimes it has to do with cookies, Gateway time out, or many other reasons. but there is 1 sure thing. It is the server. Start by looking at your .htaccess and make sure there is no issue. Afterwards I would look over your API and ensure you don't have duplicates or code errors.

Comment: @Mokey I will take a look at the .htaaccess - I know the request is not even making it to the API we have logs set up and we do not even see the request at the time of the error. That is how it led to IIS and connection problems. It is just not very descriptive and very hard to determine where and why the error happened. How does everyone else deal with this? Web Browsers?

Comment: I'm not a pro at APIs, but I know I always double check everything manually with IIS. using returns and stuff like Postman: https://www.getpostman.com/ Stuff like this will help your headache.

Comment: On Windows servers, before the request even makes it to IIS it is first consumed by HTTP.sys.  check that log (different than the iis logs) and see if the errors are generating from there.  The error message from HTTP.sys may have better info.   Additionally if your application pool queue is being overwhelmed (check the queue length) HTTP.sys will return a 503. Not sure if UNIX used HTTP.sys.

Comment: This is all on windows server - For the queue length I do get 503 if I exceed which is what I expected. Thanks for the info, where are the HTTP.sys logs located? I am pretty sure it is the connection dropping error I just don't know how to catch those in the application and re-process the message since it is just a 500 and nothing else.

Comment: based on my understanding IS server is able to drop the connection at any time but does not indicate that the connection was dropped which is the part I am confused but and dont understand why it would not do that.

Comment: c:\windows\system32\LogFiles\HTTPERR

Comment: also did you setup a failed request trace?  and check the event log-  while the 500 error itself will not be logged, the underlying issue may show up there e.g. if your app pool is being recycled it will show up in the event log and would explain the 10 messages in a row failing, then working again.